# AlwaysEncrypted and ASP.NET Identity

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-identity, sql-server-2016

I want to apply **AlwaysEncrypted** to the **UserName** column in the **AspNetUsers** table.

I have a database seeder that is meant to insert a few users if they don't exist. When I run the application and hit login for the first time, the seeder executes, but it crashes on this line:

```
var result = this.userManager.Create(user, this.pass);
```

with the following error message:

```
"Operand type clash: nvarchar(256) encrypted with (encryption_type = 'DETERMINISTIC', encryption_algorithm_name = 'AEAD_AES_256_CBC_HMAC_SHA_256', column_encryption_key_name = 'CEK_Auto1', column_encryption_key_database_name = 'TestDb') is incompatible with varchar\r\nStatement(s) could not be prepared."
```

Instead of crashing on that line, the result would normally be populated with an error similar to ***Username is already taken***

If I comment out the seeder entirely, it stops on this line without returning anything:

```
var user = await userManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
```

Is there anything I need to change in order to have *AlwaysEncrypted* working with *Identity's* *UserName*?

Comment: You should either use *asp.net-identity* or *asp.net-identity-2* tag, not both.

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm having the same issue